# How to use if or try catch block inside server tag

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am wondering if it is possible to use an if statement or a try catch block within a server tag? ie:

```
'<%= if(grid!=null){((DropDownList)this.grid.FindControl("SRPType")).ClientID} %>'
```

Comment: You mentioned this is inside a <script> block in javascript. Please provide the entire block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% try { %>

    <%= (grid != null) ?
            ((DropDownList)this.grid.FindControl("SRPType")).ClientID : ""
    %>
<% }
   catch {
    ... exception handling
   }
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of  using the <%= %> syntax, use <% %> and call [Response.Write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525585%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to write the output value, eg:

```
<%
    if(grid!=null)
    {
       try
       {
           var myList=(DropDownList)this.grid.FindControl("SRPType");
           if (myList!=null)
               Response.Write( myList.ClientID);
           else
               Response.Write("Where's my listbox?");
       }
       catch(Exception exc)
       {
          //Report error, maybe warn user
       }
    }

%>
```

Comment: Can't.  It is inside a <Script> tag in javascript.

Comment: Then please provide the relevant block, not just a part of it

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about exceptions, but you can always use inline if statement...

```
<%=(grid != null ? ((DropDownList)this.grid.FindControl("SRPType")).ClientID : "" )%>
```